# Why is my CSS file not linking in my html file?

Tags: html, css

I have made an HTML file which has the following...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Cell Corporations</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="research">
            <p class="research-header">Research</p>
            <p class="research-desc"> Research cells in order to culture more types. </p>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Which clearly states the `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />` to my stylesheet

In my style sheet includes the following...

```
research {
    background-color: '#4784e6';
}
```

The HTML and CSS is in the same path.
However, It should run the CSS code with the HTML but all I get is this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YVBW.png)
What Am I doing wrong?

I tried searching and It said that I may have done something wrong like 'placing the link in the wrong place' or 'not linking it correctly' But ive already covered and corrected all of those but it still didnt work.

Comment: P.S. Ive tried to look at it using Ctrl+Shift+C but there seems to be no errors what so ever, CSS is just not showing up.

Answer (score 6):

You forgot the prepending dot in you css file. `.research` and then the css value without single quotes. Thanks again to @PiFanatic !

```css
.research {
    background-color: #4784e6;
}
```

Comment: Also, it shoud read `background-color: #4784e6;` (without the single quotes)

Comment: it would be good to vote to close instead of answer a "typo" question .. but instead we are upvoting, answering such useless and basic questions